# looping and print a list of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

```
var firstAm = '<li>12:00 AM</li>';
                        $('#time').append(firstAm);
                        for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
                            var am = '<li>' + i + ':00 AM</li>';

                            $('#time').append(am);
                        }
```

With above code I produced 1 hour interval, but I wish to produce something like
12:15 AM
12:30 AM
12:45 AM
which have 15 min different.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ycjkqc0g/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

var end = new Date(date);
end.setHours(end.getHours() + 12);

while (date < end) {
  var am = '<li>' + convert24HourTo12Hour(date.getHours()) + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ' AM</li>';

  $('#time').append(am);
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 15);
}


function convert24HourTo12Hour(h) {
  return (h + 11) % 12 + 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: 1:0 AM? I think u missed something

Comment: try to run the result, you will see something is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0);
var html = '';
for (i=0;i<12*4*2;i++) {
    var h = ('0'+d.getHours()).slice(-2);
    var m = ('0'+d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    var s = ('0'+d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    var ampm = '';
    if (h >= 12) {
      ampm = 'pm';
    } else {
      ampm = 'am';
    }
    html += '<li>' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + ' ' + ampm + '</li>';
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 15);
}
$(html).wrap('<ul></ul>');
$('#time').append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more loop inside the for loop as,

```
for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    for ( min = 0; min < 3; min++ ) {
        var am = '<li>' + i  + ':' + min * 15 + 'AM</li>';
        $('#time').append(am);
    }
}
```

In the inner loop you are basically printing the time in minutes as 0, 15, 30 and 45.

If you want to print it as '00' for hour, then you can format the number min*15 to a two digit value and use it.